# Interpreting regression coefficients in R

Tags: r, regression, lm

I'm trying to fit a x*log(x) model to the data. The fitting is performed successfully but I have difficulties in interpreting the resulting coefficients. Here a snapshot of my code.

```
x <- c(6, 11, 16, 21, 26, 31, 36, 41, 46, 51)
y <- c(5.485, 6.992, 7.447, 8.134, 8.524, 8.985, 9.271, 9.647, 10.561, 9.971)

fit <- lm(y ~ x*log(x))
coef(fit)
> (Intercept)           x      log(x)    x:log(x) 
3.15224227  0.10020022  1.12588040 -0.01322249
```

How I should interpret these coefficients? Let's call them a,b,c,d. Where I should put them in the formula "x*log(x)"?

Comment: StackOverflow is intended more for programming questions. Help with interpreting statistical models might be a better fit for crossvalidated.com.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear in my question. I don't mean interpreting the values itself of the coefficients. Let's call the 4 coefficients a,b,c,d: the fitting is actually for what function? for instance, a + b*xlog(c*x)?

Comment: The documentation in `?lm` has a detailed description of the meaning of model formula, I suggest you read it carefully. Specifically, `*` has a special (non-arithmetic) meaning in that context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As written, the model you are fitting is

```
E(y) = a + b*x + c*log(x) + d*x*log(x)
```

If you really did want to fit the model `a + b*x*log(c*x)` you would need to figure out that `a + b*x*(log(c)+log(x)) = a + b*log(c)*x + b*x*log(x)`, fit `y ~ x + x:log(x)`, and back-calculate the parameters accordingly.

Or you might be interested in `y~I(x*log(x))`?

What is the model you *actually* want to fit?

Comment: +1 Just beat me there. The only other thing I was going to suggest was that maybe they are really wanting to use `nls`, if they want a coefficient inside the log function.

Comment: The model I want to fit is "a+b*x*log(c*x)". So your answer is perfect, thanks a lot!