# How to interpret the linear regression coefficient summarized by R?

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

Please find reprex below:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Work days for January from 2010 - 2018
data = data.frame(work_days = c(20,21,22,20,20,22,21,21),
           sale = c(1205,2111,2452,2054,2440,1212,1211,2111))

# Apply linear regression
model = lm(sale ~ work_days, data)

summary(model)
Call:
lm(formula = sale ~ work_days, data = data)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-677.8 -604.5  218.7  339.0  645.3 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  2643.82    5614.16   0.471    0.654
work_days     -38.05     268.75  -0.142    0.892

Residual standard error: 593.4 on 6 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.00333,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.1628 
F-statistic: 0.02005 on 1 and 6 DF,  p-value: 0.892
```

Could you please help me understand if the coefficients 
**Every work day decreases the sale by 38.05** ?

```
data = data.frame(work_days = c(20,21,22,20,20,22,21,21),
           sale = c(1212,1211,2111,1205,2111,2452,2054,2440))

model = lm(sale ~ work_days, data)

summary(model)
Call:
lm(formula = sale ~ work_days, data = data)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-686.8 -301.0   -8.6  261.3  599.7 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  -6220.0     4555.9  -1.365    0.221
work_days      386.6      218.1   1.772    0.127

Residual standard error: 481.5 on 6 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3437,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2343 
F-statistic: 3.142 on 1 and 6 DF,  p-value: 0.1267
```

*Does this mean,*

**Every workday increases the sales by 387 ?
How about the negative intercept ?**

Similar questions but couldnt apply the learnings:

[Interpreting regression coefficients in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695797/interpreting-regression-coefficients-in-r)

[Interpreting coefficients from Logistic Regression from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35291428/interpreting-coefficients-from-logistic-regression-from-r)

[Linear combination of regression coefficients in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53561699/linear-combination-of-regression-coefficients-in-r)

Comment: Better suited for Cross Validated (stats.stackexchange.com)? Here are some tips: 1. Intercept is the point where your regression line crosses the x axis, that is, when your explanatory variable is zero, the explained variable has that value. 2. Coefficient is the change in explained variable by every 1 unit change in explanatory variable. 3. It's a good idea to check those fields named `Pr(>t)`. Usually you disregard regression if value is above 0.5. 4. Check R-squared: it's roughly the proportion of variance explained by the model, very low in your examples.

Comment: The p-values from the F-statistics are very high. You cannot conclude from these models that there is a relationship between sales and work days. Also, you have very low variation in the number of workdays. It can be expected that other variables have a much stronger impact (such as month/season if this is monthly data).

Comment: I think the OP wants to get a sense of how to interpret the output. I hardly think of developing a model let alone a conclusion on the basis of this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could you please help me understand if the coefficients **Every work day decreases the sale by 38.05** ?

Yes and no. Given only the 8 data points the best regression line has a negative slope of -38.05 which appears to be counterintuitive.

However, you need to take the standard error of this -38.05 value into account, which is 268.75. So the result can be translated into "in this sample it looks like the slope is negative but it might as well be positive, anything between '-38.05 + 2*268.75' and '-38.05 - 2*268.75' is a resonable guess. So do not extrapolate from this small sample to anything other than this sample.

Also look at

```
Multiple R-squared:  0.00333
```

This means, less than 1 % of the sample variance can be explained with this regression. Do not take it to serious and try to explain numbers from such a small sample.

> **Every workday increases the sales by 387 ? How about the negative intercept ?**

Judging only from the small sample you investigated, it looks like every workday increased sales by 387. However, the standard error is high and thus you cannot tell, whether additional workdays increase or decrease sales outside of this small sample. The whole model is not significant so nobody claims, this model is better then pure guessing.

> **How about the negative intercept ?**

You forced the computer to calculate a linear model. That model will allow you to compute stupid values like "what if sales were a linear function of work days and a month had negative or zero workdays"? You could of course force R to predict a linear model, in which zero workdays lead to zero sales and this brings us back on topic. Forcing R to compute a model through the point (0; 0) takes the following syntax:

```
model <- lm(sales ~ work_days - 1, data = data)
```

Comment: Thanks for descriptive solution.

Could you please help me interpret:
Residual standard error: 481.5 on 6 degrees of freedom
Adjusted R-squared:  0.2343 
F-statistic: 3.142 on 1 and 6 DF

Comment: Linear regression is a complicated matter worth reading a book about. For the brevity of this 600 characters format: Do not mind residual standard error, degrees of freedom or F-statistic at this stage. Just look at them as a means to determine the p-value. Multiple-$R^2$ increases whenever you apply more predictors. Adjusted-$R^2$ tries to eliminate that problem but still remain similar to $R^2$. When time comes, try to get a deeper understanding of linear regression -- it will pay off some day.

Answer (score 1):

The Intercept of the regression line is interpreted as the predicted `sale` when `work_days` is equal to `zero`. If the predictor (`work_days` in this case)  can't be zero, then it doesn't make sense. The slope of the regression line or the predicted estimate `-38.5` can be interpreted as for each additional increase in `work_days`, sale measurement is reduced by `-38.05`.